# Impulse response of an infinite-length system

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, impulse-response

I have a system which is expressed as following:
$$y[n] = x[n] - \alpha y[n-N]$$ where $y[n]$ is the output and $x[n]$ is the input.

When I take the z-transform of both sides, I've found the transfer function as $$H(z)=\frac{1}{1+\alpha z^{-N}}$$.

However, I need to find the impulse response of this system but I couldn't find $h[n]$. Can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Cconsider the following pair of signals and their transforms:

If $g[n]$ has a Z-transform $G(z)$ then the **expanded** (zero stuffed) signal $h[n]$ has the Z-transform $H(z) = G(z^N)$, where

$$ h[n] = \begin{cases} {g[\frac{n}{N}] ~~~,~~~ n = m N  \\ 0 ~~~~~~~~~,~~~ \text{otherwise}  \tag{1}}\end{cases} $$

Looking at the given Z-transform :
$$H(z) = \frac{ 1}{ 1 - \alpha z^{-N} }$$

it can be seen that if $H(z) = G(z^N)$ where

$$G(z)= \frac{ 1}{ 1 - \alpha z^{-1} }$$

and $g[n] = \alpha^n u[n] $.

Then you can simply conlcude that :

$$ h[n] = \alpha^{n/N} ~u[n/N] =  \begin{cases} {\alpha^{n/N}  ~~ ,~~ n = m N, m = 0,1,..  \\ 0 ~~~~~~~~~,~~ \text{otherwise} }\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Find the impulse response corresponding to

$$\tilde{H}(z)=\frac{1}{1+\alpha z^{-1}}\tag{1}$$

and then try to figure out what happens to the impulse response if you replace $z$ by $z^N$. (Note that $H(z)=\tilde{H}(z^N)$).

**HINT 2:**

Answer the following questions for yourself: what is the impulse response corresponding to $H(z)=1+z^{-1}$? And what is the impulse response corresponding to $H(z^N)=1+z^{-N}$? So what does replacing $z$ by $z^N$ do to the impulse response?

Comment: The impulse response of this function is $(-a)^{n} u(n)$. But I'm asking $z^{-N}$ version. Please can you help me?

Comment: @Jason: I know what you're asking, but as you might know, this is no homework service. I tried to help you but you need to show a bit of effort on your side. Did you actually try to think about what happens when $z$ is replaced by $z^N$?

Comment: @MattL. Sir, this is not a homework, just a simple question. I put an effort as you can see. I did everything and stuck at this step. If I replace z with $z^{N}$, does it mean shifting by N? And the result is h[n] = $(-a)^{n-N}u(n-N)$. Am I right?

Comment: @Ben it is z/(z-1).

Comment: Sorry I misread, I thought you meant step function.

It's even easier because it's an impulse response. You simply need to find the inverse transform of H(z), then you will have the impulse response for each sample.

Comment: @Ben Sir, I know I have to find the inverse z-transform to find the impulse response but I couldn't find it. Is this correct $(-a)^{n-N} u(n-N)$ Please can you help me?

Comment: @Jason: No, it's not a shift. A *multiplication* by $z^{-N}$ would be a shift, but that's not what you have here.

Comment: @Jason: I added another hint to my answer.

Comment: @MattL. Sir, the first impulse response is dirac(n) + dirac(n-1) whereas the second one is  dirac(n) + dirac(n-N). So, what should I conclude here?

Comment: @Jason: You should try to see the way the impulse response is transformed by changing $z$ to $z^N$.

Comment: @MattL. Sir, sorry for disturbing you again but I finally find this result after plotting the impulse response in Matlab. h[n] = $(-a)^{n} u[n*N]$. Can you please let me know whether I'm right or wrong?

Comment: @Jason: It's not right. Note that $u[nN]$ is the same as $u[n]$. What actually happens is that replacing $z$ by $z^N$ inserts $N-1$ zeros between the impulse response values. Look back at the simple example in my answer ("Hint 2"), then you'll see that that is what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to find the impulse response in such cases by substituting $x(n) = \delta(n)$ and $y(n) = h(n)$ (after all it is an 'impulse' response). That gives you
$$h(n) = \delta(n) - \alpha h(n-N)$$
If the system is causal (no negative time indices),
$$\begin{aligned}
h(0) &= 1 \\
h(1) &= 0 \\
h(2) &= 0 \\
&\vdots \\
h(N) &= -\alpha h(0) = -\alpha\\
h(N+1) &= 0 \\
&\vdots \\
h(2N) &= -\alpha h(N) = \alpha^2\\
\therefore h(kN) &= (-1)^k \alpha^k, \ k = 0,1,2,\ldots 
\end{aligned}$$
This is just an upsampled version of the sequence $h(k) = (-1)^k \alpha^k$, with an upsampling factor of $N$. For $N=5, \alpha=0.8$, this is what the impulse response looks like for the first $100$ samples

[image]